# HTML details tag opening direction? How to change?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to figure out a way to reverse the direction of an open `<details>` tag in HTML so that the summary is placed ABOVE instead of the default BELOW.

Is it possible to do it with CSS only? CSS+Javascript?

[Here is a simple JSFiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/vyksxnfa/)

Comment: With CSS..doubtful but I think it would be poor UX. I would scroll down to the summary, click it and the box could open upwards and off the screen.

Comment: @Paulie_D the UX is out of my decision :-(

Comment: @Kroltan JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a fixed size, you can set `details` as `position: relative`, set it's size for closed and open state and use `top` and `bottom` to adjust its children:

```css
details { height: 20px; position: relative; width: 100%;}
details[open] { height: 40px;}

details span {position: absolute; top: 0;background-color: red;}
summary {background-color:blue; position: absolute; bottom: 0;}

details[open] ::-webkit-details-marker
{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
    <details>
                
        <span>Trying to open this upwards</span>
<summary>Test</summary>
        </details>
</body>
```

And do not forget the `::-webkit-details-marker` to fix the arrow direction ;)

Comment: Best solution so far! I just have to calculate heights with JS if needed! Thanks! Will mark as correct if no other solution is posted.

Answer (score 2):

```
details {background-color:white; color:white;}
details[open] {background-color:red;}
summary {
    background-color:blue; 
    position: relative;
    top: calc(1em + 4px);
}
span {
    position: relative;
    top: calc(-1.2em + 4px);
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m7yy82ab/)

Comment: This is a good solution. Just wanted to point out that if you have a lot of content or a line-break  in `span`  then it will overflow the summary. In other words, the `span` within details can't really be dynamic.